# How to check Kendo tree-view databound event in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, telerik, kendo-treeview

I have an API call which gives result and I am assigning it as kendo tree-view data-source. I get API result quickly but result is too heavy which takes time to build/render kendo tree-view.

So I want to keep a loading icon till it is being rendered. But I do not find any [dataBound](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular) /widgetRendered event as kendo-grid has.

Check below link for reference. This is how I am creating tree using kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource().

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/AngularJS/toggle-nodes-with-single-click

Any alternative how can I have such events like dataBound or WidgetRendered ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**For `dataBound`**

Have a look at the **[DOJO - TreeView Databound with AngularJS](http://dojo.telerik.com/@paritosh/AzIMe)** I've made.

You can use the same `k-options` attribute as there is for `kendoGrid`

```
<div kendo-tree-view="tree"
     k-data-source="treeData"
     k-options="treeOptions">
</div>
```

In `controller`, the `k-options` will be having `dataBound` function.

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
   checkboxes: {
        template: "<input type='checkbox' #= item.disabled # />"
   },
   template: ' <span style="color: #= item.color #">#= item.text #</span>',
   dataBound: function(e){
       console.log(e.sender);
       //do whatever you want!
   }
};
```